# Beginning with SQL

Tags: sql

I am enthusiastic to enter the world of Databases through SQL, but I don't know if there's  prerequisites of any significance and I only know C# and Java.

Besides these, what tools do I need? I have Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio. What else do I need? Is it necessary to download a server OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server Express are sufficient to learn the basics of a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS.)  You can learn T-SQL (SQL Server's ANSI-SQL dialect,) schema design, Object-Relational Mapping, and more.  SQL Express runs on Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7.

Oracle also provides an Express version, and there are other free options such as MySQL and SQLite.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely install one of the free databases (Oracle Express, SQL Server Express).  I have used both of those.  You might also want to check out [this free tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).  It will help you learn SQL syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to try SQL Server Express, it is the easiest server to work with if you are developing with C#. If you would like to learn SQL using Java almost any data base would be good.

A data base server it's a software like any other, you will have to communicate with it through your own program, making a connection, throwing SQL commands and interpreting its results. If you only wanted to learn SQL you also could install a client for the chosen data base server and learn through it, after that you could try to connect your program to this data base. In this case [SQLite](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) would work pretty good for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a special server OS. SQL Server will run just fine on your development machine if you are just using it to learn. You'll want to make sure that SQL Server is installed in addition to Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to try either [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). They're both free, much easier to install than SQL Server, and run on more platforms.

Comment: If they are using a Windows environment, I've found getting C# to work with SqlServer significantly easier than MySQL. Installing SqlServer seemed about as easy as MySQL for me.

Answer (score 2):

To start, I would look at the W3 tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp .

I used MySQL , also get the Workbench and WAMP(or LAMP). Then start building! It's good to do something you would use.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will run on your development system, and SQL Server Management Studio 2008 is a good tool to work with in SQL 2008.

If you want to connect through your network though, you'll need to configure the Network Area Surface to accept TCP Clients connections.